# How can I put a Xamarin Backdrop Page (SfBackdropPage) inside a Xamarin Tabbed View (SfTabView)?

Tags: xamarin, syncfusion

**I want one of my TabItem to be a Backdrop page, how can I do that?**

I tried to put it inside a TapItem, but it didn't work.

```
<tabView:SfTabView>
   <tabView:SfTabItem Title=" DOCUMENT ">
      <StackLayout>
         <backdrop:BackdropBackLayer>
            <StackLayout>
               <ListView>
                  <ListView.ItemsSource>
                     <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                        <x:String>Appetizers</x:String>
                        <x:String>Soups</x:String>
                     </x:Array>
                  </ListView.ItemsSource>
               </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
         </backdrop:BackdropBackLayer>
         <backdrop:BackdropFrontLayer>
            <Grid BackgroundColor="White"></Grid>
         </backdrop:BackdropFrontLayer>
      </StackLayout>
   </tabView:SfTabItem>
</tabView:SfTabView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for directly adding `SfBackdropPage` as a child to `SfTabView`.
The `SfTabView` accept only the type of `view`. `SfBackdropPage` is a page.

You can see this thread:https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/151034/display-sfbackdroppage-in-sftabview

Iyyappan Mani comes from Syncfusion, answer this question directly.